# Reduce Quality of Image/Stream Before Saving

Tags: c#, stream

I'm trying to take an input stream (a zip file of images) and extract each file. But i must reduce the quality of each image before they are saved (if quality < 100). I have tried the following but it never compresses the image:

```
public void UnZip(Stream inputStream, string destinationPath, int quality = 80) {
    using (var zipStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream)) {
        ZipEntry entry;

        while ((entry = zipStream.GetNextEntry()) != null) {
            var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(destinationPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + entry.Name);
            var fullPath = directoryPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + Path.GetFileName(entry.Name);

            // Create the stream to unzip the file to
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
                // Write the zip stream to the stream
                if (entry.Size != 0) {
                    var size = 2048;
                    var data = new byte[2048];

                    while (true) {
                        size = zipStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

                        if (size > 0)
                            stream.Write(data, 0, size);
                        else
                            break;
                    }
                }

                // Compress the image and save it to the stream
                if (quality < 100)
                    using (var image = Image.FromStream(stream)) {
                        var info = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
                        var @params = new EncoderParameters(1);
                        @params.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality);
                        image.Save(stream, info[1], @params);
                    }
                }

                // Save the stream to disk
                using (var fs = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create)) {
                    stream.WriteTo(fs);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could show me what i'm doing wrong. Also any advice on tidying it up would be appreciated as the code's grown abit ugly. Thanks

Comment: You question and your code are contradictory.  "Unzip" implies decompressing, and your question is about why it's not compressing.  Can you be more clear with your question?

Comment: Hi Peter, i needed to unzip the zip file and then compress the resulting files individually. This saves abit of disk space. I think Scott's answer is going to help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't be using the same stream to save the compressed image.  The MSDN documentation clearly says: "Do not save an image to the same stream that was used to construct the image. Doing so might damage the stream." ([MSDN Article on Image.Save(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142148))

```
using (var compressedImageStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(compressedImageStream, info[1], @params);
}
```

Also, what file format are you encoding into?  You haven't specified.  You're just getting the second encoder found.  You shouldn't rely on the order of the results.  Search for a specific codec instead:

```
var encoder = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().Where(x => x.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid).SingleOrDefault()
```

... and don't forget to check if the encoder doesn't exist on your system:

```
if (encoder != null)
{ .. }
```

The Quality parameter doesn't have meaning for all file formats.  I assume you might be working with JPEGs?  Also, keep in mind that 100% JPEG Quality != Lossless Image.  You can still encode with Quality = 100 and reduce space.

Comment: Thanks this worked a treat. Thanks once more for the additional advice on encoding.

Answer (score 1):

There is no code to compress the image after you've extracted it from the zip stream.  All you seem to be doing is getting the unzipped data into a MemoryStream, then proceeding the write the image to the same stream based on quality information (which may or may not compress an image, depending on the codec).    I would first recommend not writing to the same stream you're reading from.  Also, what "compression" you get out of the Encoder.Quality property depends on the type of image--which you haven't provided any detail on.   If the image type supports compression and the incoming image quality is lower than 100 to start, you won't get any reduction in size.  Also, you've not provided any information with regard to that.  Long story short, you haven't provided enough information for anyone to give you a real answer.

Comment: They are specifying the target file format by 'info[1]' which is just returning the second encoder found in the system... which is typically the JPEG encoder.

Comment: I would not recommend relying on that.  And if the original image stream was already JPEG with a quality of less than quality supplied to the method (default of 80) then JPEG can't compress more than it already has--thus giving the appearance of not compressing anything

Comment: I wouldn't recommend relying on that either. You're right though.  You do have to consider that the image might already be JPEG encoded with a similar or lesser quality setting.